# Zeroing out a factor of a term in the elements of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

Each element of my matrix is zero or has the form $k_1 a_{i,n} + k_2 b_{i,n}$. How can I replace all the $a_{i,n}$s by zero?

```
{{{0. - 0.000565035 Subscript[a, i, 1] + 0.00187682 Subscript[b, i, 1], 
   0. - 0.00176323 Subscript[a, i, 1] - 0.000565035 Subscript[b, i, 1]}, 
  {0., 0.}, 
  {0. - 0.00428076 Subscript[a, i, 3] - 0.00380882 Subscript[b, i, 3], 
   0. - 0.00421293 Subscript[a, i, 3] - 0.00428076 Subscript[b, i, 3]}}, 
 {{0., 0.}, 
  {0. + 0.00995524 Subscript[a, i, 2] + 0.00978341 Subscript[b, i, 2], 
   0. + 0.00932789 Subscript[a, i, 2] + 0.00995524 Subscript[b, i, 2]}, 
  {0., 0.}}, 
 {{-0.00428076 Subscript[a, i, 1] - 0.00380882 Subscript[b, i, 1], 
   -0.00421293 Subscript[a, i, 1] - 0.00428076 Subscript[b, i, 1]}, 
  {0., 0.}, 
  {0. - 0.00924663 Subscript[a, i, 3] - 0.0114643 Subscript[b, i, 3], 
   0. - 0.00745795 Subscript[a, i, 3] - 0.00924663 Subscript[b, i, 3]}}}
```

Comment: YourExpr/.Subscript[a,i,_]->0  does it. Note: you have a - followed by , on the last two lines, but I suspect that is just a scrape-n-paste typo.

Comment: You might be interested in point 3 in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395

Comment: Thank you, yeah that works. Thank you so much

Comment: If you meant to notify Bill, you should use @Bill to make sure your response is seen.  (Author's of posts are always notified when someone makes a comment.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ok.Thank you

Comment: @Bill Thank you Bill

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
m = {{{0. - 0.000565035 Subscript[a, i, 1] + 
     0.00187682 Subscript[b, i, 1], 
    0. - 0.00176323 Subscript[a, i, 1] - 
     0.000565035 Subscript[b, i, 1]}, {0., 
    0.}, {0. - 0.00428076 Subscript[a, i, 3] - 
     0.00380882 Subscript[b, i, 3], 
    0. - 0.00421293 Subscript[a, i, 3] - 
     0.00428076 Subscript[b, i, 3]}}, {{0., 
    0.}, {0. + 0.00995524 Subscript[a, i, 2] + 
     0.00978341 Subscript[b, i, 2], 
    0. + 0.00932789 Subscript[a, i, 2] + 
     0.00995524 Subscript[b, i, 2]}, {0., 
    0.}}, {{-0.00428076 Subscript[a, i, 1] - 
     0.00380882 Subscript[b, i, 1], -0.00421293 Subscript[a, i, 1] - 
     0.00428076 Subscript[b, i, 1]}, {0., 
    0.}, {0. - 0.00924663 Subscript[a, i, 3] - 
     0.0114643 Subscript[b, i, 3], 0. - 0.00745795 Subscript[a, i, 3],
     0.00924663 Subscript[b, i, 3]}}};
```

Then

```
m1=m /. Subscript[a, i, n_] -> 0;

MatrixForm[m1]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: @ Alexei Boulbitch, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It can sometimes be more efficient to make a definition upon `Subscript` itself, within [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) if needed, if your data is large.

```
(* m from Alexei's answer *)
big = RandomChoice[m, 50000];

r1 = big /. Subscript[a, i, n_] -> 0;                 // RepeatedTiming

r2 = Block[{Subscript}, Subscript[a, i, _] = 0; big]; // RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> ```
> {0.470, Null}
>
> {0.27, Null}
>
> True
> ```